# "I am yet to see" versus "I have yet to see"

Tags: phrases, idioms, word-usage, popular-refrains

What is the difference between

> I am yet to see X

and

> I have yet to see X

and in which situations would each be preferred?

Comment: Some random data: “I have yet to see” gives 10× the google hits that “I am yet to see” does; but at the same time “is yet to come” has 10× more than “has yet to come”...